# Leakage of information about selfish mining - what message is responsible?

Tags: message, testing, regtest, selfish-mining

A few weeks back I had asked a [question about how honest nodes could detect a Selfish Mine Attack and if there were mechanisms that would disclose selfish mining](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37655/implicit-tacit-mechanisms-in-bitcoin-core-disclosing-selfish-mining).

In a very first step: I've slightly changed the Bitcoin source code in a way that a selfish node (built from that modified code) run on regtest shouldn't shouldn't report its secret blocks. Now, this doesn't ALWAYS work out because a honest node connected to the selfish node somehow, in a certain scenario, gets to know about hidden blocks and updates its blockchain.
I would like to know **through what kind of messages/mechanisms a selfish node could blabber out about its headers and eventually blocks, if not through headers and block messages?**
Or do I miss something?

For a better understanding of my question, I'll sketch it here (h=honest node; s=selfish node):

1. **SCENARIO** (*failing selfish mine*): first generate secret block, then connect to honest node:

   - h: start bitcoin server.
   - s: start bitcoin server.
   - s: create block #1 (child of genesis block)
   - h: addnode "s" add
     ---*version, verack, getaddr and ping messages exchanged (no pong messages!?)*---
     ---*wireshark strangely doesn't show any getheaders, headers, getdata or block messages*---
      *BUT ...*
   - h: updatetip: best= block#1!!!

***How is this possible without having sent even headers messages, in first place?***

WHEREAS:

2. **SCENARIO** (*successfull selfish mine*): first connect to honest node, then generate secret block

   - h: start bitcoin server.
   - s: start bitcoin server.
     ---*version, verack, getaddr and ping messages exchanged (no pong messages!?)*---
   - s: create block #1 (child of genesis block)
     ---*honest node doesn't react and wireshark verifies this by showing no packet exchange*---

---

**EDIT:**
I looked up hash of block#1 (in reversed byte order) in EVERY message's hexdump but it wasn't there - still honest node was able to update to hidden chain in 1. Scenario!?

Comment: That's very strange. You should get, at minimum, an `inv`, a `getdata`, and a `block` message.

Comment: @NickODell: With 2. Scenario everythings going as planned.. but 1. Scenario is strange but true.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you post a wireshark log of scenario #1 to a filehosting site, and link it here?

Comment: @NickODell: This is a wireshark-specific pcapng-file: http://www.filedropper.com/selfishnessfailedpackets can you open it? If not I'll upload hexdumps one by one and upload them. And this is a screenshot: http://www.filedropper.com/selfishminingtest

Comment: I can open it. I don't see the same thing -  I see pong, getheaders, headers. Want a screenshot, or do you see it too?

Comment: Ok weird. I didn't see any of those, yes please can you send a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24983/discussion-between-aliakbar-ahmadi-and-nick-odell).